# Calling a function in factory boy test with **kwargs

Tags: python, testing, factory-boy

I'm trying to write a test in which i have to call a model's function which accepts **kwargs 
here is function from my model

```
def send_message(self, **kwargs):
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.conf import settings
    send_mail(
            recipient_list=[self.email_from,],
            from_email=settings.INFORMATION_FROM,
            **kwargs
        )
```

and this is where i am trying to access this mention function in test

```
def test_send_message(self):
    send_message = self.user.send_message()
    print send_message
```

and getting this error **TypeError: send_message() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a Django's [`send_email()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#send-mail), it requires at least 4 arguments to be given:

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)
```

You are not passing the `subject` and the `message` to the `send_message` function. Fix it:

```
def test_send_message(self):
    send_message = self.user.send_message(subject="Test subject", message="Test message")
    print send_message
```